# Can't use includedCheckedBags attribute in Amadeus Flight Offers API

Tags: amadeus

When I try to create a request in the test environment that returns tickets with checked bags only I receive the following error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 2668,
      "title": "PARAMETER COMBINATION INVALID/RESTRICTED",
      "detail": "Pricing option includedCheckedBags is true but officeId is not allowed",
      "status": 400
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying this from the API explorer in the test environment.

This is the full body of my request:

```
{
  "currencyCode": "EUR",
  "originDestinations": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "originLocationCode": "MAD",
      "destinationLocationCode": "NYC",
      "departureDateTimeRange": {
        "date": "2019-09-01",
        "time": "10:00:00",
        "timeWindow" : "6H"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "originLocationCode": "NYC",
      "destinationLocationCode": "MIA",
      "departureDateTimeRange": {
        "date": "2019-09-03",
        "time": "17:00:00",
        "timeWindow": "2H"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "originLocationCode": "MCO",
      "destinationLocationCode": "MAD",
      "departureDateTimeRange": {
        "date": "2019-09-07",
        "time": "17:00:00",
        "timeWindow": "6H"
      }
    }
  ],
  "travelers": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "travelerType": "ADULT",
      "fareOptions": [
        "STANDARD"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "sources": [
    "GDS", "PYTON"
  ],
  "searchCriteria": {
    "maxFlightOffers": 50,
    "pricingOptions" : {
        "includedCheckedBagsOnly" : true
    },
    "flightFilters": {
        "connectionRestriction":
        {
            "airportChangeAllowed" : false,
            "maxNumberOfConnections" : 1 
        },
        "cabinRestrictions":
        [{
            "cabin" : "BUSINESS", 
            "coverage" : "MOST_SEGMENTS",
            "originDestinationIds" : ["1", "2", "3"]
        }]
      }
  }
}
```

I would expect this to work, since it is documented in the API page, but the error message is not helpful at all.

Comment: Bug reported: the support team is working on it. I will update the response when it’s fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything has been fixed in the test and in the production environment.

Comment: Thanks Anthony. Do you have an ETA on Pyton? It's odd that it appears on the documentation but isn't working yet.

Comment: No ETA for the moment, the dev team is working on it. You are totally right, the swagger will be updated very soon with a cleaner version.

Comment: I updates the answer as everything is working fine now. Thanks a lot for your feedback!